# MongoDB - Store Indexes on SSD & Data Collections on Magnetic?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to store index collections on separate high-performance storage (i.e. flash/SSD) while keeping data collections on lower-cost conventional storage?  The performance issues I am seeing using MongoDB appear to be related to index maintenance operations, and I am having to partition my data across database buckets on a single instance in order to avoid drastic dips in write performance - a solution that will only scale for so long.  Therefore I would like to use SSD for indexes, but it doesn't make sense to pay for high-performance storage where it's not warranted (data collections).

The only discussion I have found on this subject is somewhat dated:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-965

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you are asking with MongoDB.

The work around is splitting your collections into multiple databases.  MongoDB cannot do joins, so there is not really a trade off at the data level.  Your application will have to manage multiple connections to multiple databases.

- Put your high-performance collections on SSD servers with larger RAM
  allocations.
- Put your lower performance collections on slower spindle
  disk or AWS EBS servers.